# NHibernate query mapped collection

Tags: linq, nhibernate, paging, linq-to-nhibernate

In my ASP.NET web-application I use NHibernate to persist my "User"-Instances, where each of them has a "Entries" - collection. It is a typical one-to-many mapping and it works just fine. The mapping-code for the entries looks like this:

```
<bag name="Entries" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
   <key column="UserID" />
   <one-to-many class="MyApp.Entities.Entry, MyApp.Entities" />
</bag>
```

Now I have a page, where I want to display a grid with all the entries of the logged-in user. To do so, I could simply bind the "Entries" property of the current user to the Grids "DataSource" - property. This also works just fine, but this also means, that the grids built-in paging-functionality (Telerik RadGrid) doesn't have any effect on database-performance, because all the entries will be loaded each time when displaying the grid.

Therefore I could apply my custom-paging, where I only fetch the rows which I need to display the grids current page. A typical Linq2NHibernate query looks like this:

```
var query = from entry in Session.Linq<Entry>()
                    where entry.User == currentUser
                    select entry;
query.Skip(pageNum * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Using this approach I need to extend my repository altough NHibernate has already done the mapping between User and Entry...

My question is: If I use LINQ to directly query the "Entries"-collection of my "User"-object - does this mean, that all the Entries will be loaded from the database and then filtered in memory or would this be translated to a real "database"-query, so that I could use this much more comfortable approach to implement paging?

Example:

```
myGrid.DataSource = currentUser.Entries.Skip(pageNum * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

J4I: Of course I use lazy-loading in the mapping files...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: IMPORTANT:

In the meantime I have found out, that the sample linq-expression produces really ugly SQL-code and actually uses an outer left join to compare the "User"-property. However, upgrading to NH3 and the embedded linq-provider resolves this issue and outputs much more optimized code! 

So if you consider using Linq2NHibernate - go for NH3!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ on the collection will always be LINQ-to-objects, as they don't implement IQueryable, so you'd be loading everything in memory.

A query is the only possible approach at this moment.

Comment: will this still be the case with the NH3 linq provider?

Comment: Yes, the provider sits on top of the query engine; collection management hasn't changed. You can do LINQ queries on entity collections, but not directly on retrieved objects.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation..that's a bit of a bummer as this would make linq usage far more coherent. I'm guessing that this would cause problems with dirty-tracking in collections, etc though; right?

Comment: I think it's something that *can* be implemented, but there are several design challenges to overcome.